# Insert() in uint8_t array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am new to C++, when I try to insert an element in the uint8_t array, I get the following error. Please help me in solving this.

Error

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

main.cpp:10:9: error: request for member ‘insert’ in ‘array’, which is of non-class type ‘uint8_t [5] {aka unsigned char [5]}’
   array.insert(1,0xff);
```

The code is

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  
  uint8_t array[] = {0x00, 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44};
  
  array.insert(1,0xff);
  
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++){

      cout << array[i]<< " ";

  }

  return 0;

}
```

I want the output array to be

```
array[] = {0x00, 0xff, 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44};
```

Comment: Note: `#include <string.h>` is not relevant here, and doesn't even belong in most C++ programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not something you can `insert` on, primitive types like `uint8_t` don't have functions. That's what "non-class type" means.

You need `std::vector<uint8_t>` which does have [`insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert). It's from `#include <vector>`

One thing to keep in mind is C++ has a quick and easy iterator method you can use if you don't care about the indexes:

```cpp
for (auto&& e : array) {
  cout << e << " ";
}
```

Super easy!

Putting this all together:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Tip: Avoid using namespace std, the std:: prefix exists for a reason

int main ()
{
  std::vector<uint8_t> array = {0x00, 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44};
  
  array.insert(array.begin() + 1, 0xff);
  
  for (auto&& e : array) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I know how I can copy the uint8_t array[] to std::vector<uint8_t> ?

Comment: Just use `std::vector` instead: `std::vector<uint8_t> array = {0x00, 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44};`

Comment: This is giving me a set of errors

main.cpp:14:3: error: ‘vector’ is not a member of ‘std’

   std::vector<uint8_t> array = {0x00, 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44};
   ^~~
main.cpp:14:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

   std::vector<uint8_t> array = {0x00, 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44};
                      ^
main.cpp:14:24: error: ‘array’ was not declared in this scope

   std::vector<uint8_t> array = {0x00, 0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44};

Comment: Did you `#include <vector>` as I noted?

Comment: Thanks for the comment #include <vector>. The error has now solved. Can you write an answer itself using vectors for the question since that would give me a clear solution for the question?

Comment: Added a complete example.

Comment: I get this error now
main.cpp:20:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector::insert(int, int)’
   array.insert(1,0xff);

Comment: Ah, right, `insert` takes an iterator. Adjusted.